# Action Bar remove title and reclaim space

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to remove the title from my action bar and reclaim the space it would otherwise consume for the use of menu items.

I have tried using a custom theme but so far nothing has worked.  I have tried changing the text size to 0sp, changing the color to transparent, and setting visibility to gone.

I have also tried this :

```
ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

I am targeting sdk 15+ and using the standard Android action bar (i.e. not Sherlock).

Thanks for any suggestions.

Here's what I'm talking about (the area bordered in red I want back):

[image: ActionBar]

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out the ActionBar documentation yet? There's a method, [`setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowTitleEnabled%28boolean%29) that does what you need.

Simply get a reference to your `ActionBar`, and call that with `false`:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have edited my original question to hopefully make it clearer.